# unable to recover lost data after deleting mount points in ubunu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, data-recovery, storage, root-filesystem

i have mounted two partitions on **/media** folder:

[image: show mounted partitions]

so later, i could access them through GUI **as a separated partitions** like this

[image: partitions]

by mistake, i have **deleted** the following mounting points of those partitions from **/media** using the command "**rm -rf ./***":

[image]

when i navigated to the the partitions, there is no data on each of them, all data got lost.

i could not imagine how that happened, but i have an important information on these partitions, and i hope i can recover data.

**i want to ensure if this data still present or lost forever and if lost,
Can i recover this critical data??**

Comment: It depends on what filesystem you use on these partitions https://likegeeks.com/recover-deleted-files-on-linux/amp/

Answer (score 0):

make a copy of the raw disk on the to your remaining filesystem, and that way you will have a copy of the disk that you can attempt to recover from.  maybe you want to unmount the filesystem first, but I'm not sure that's any better.

the filesystem metadata is gone, but the data is inside the block device, at least for a while, and certainly having a backup of the block device you can try different recovery methods.  You should decide what is the most important data that you want to recover.    at best, someone can poke into the filesystem and extract the data, but things like filenames are most certainly lost, even if you get some of the content back.

Comment: But how can I copy the unmounted desk to another one, you mean, I should copy /sda5 to /home that already have a data on it.

Comment: you can use a tool like dd.  you can turn a disk partition into a file, but you would have to have enough space.